# Plotting an xts object using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

I'm wanting to plot an xts object using ggplot2 but getting an error. Here is what I'm doing:

```
dates <- c("2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
value <- as.numeric(c(3, 4, 5, 6, 5))
new_df <- data_frame(dates, value)
new_df$dates <- as.Date(dates)
new_df <- as.xts(new_df[,-1], order.by = new_df$dates)
```

Now I try to plot it using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = index, y = value)) + geom_point()
```

I get the following error:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>   check.names = TRUE,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0,
>   5

I'm not quite sure what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 12):

The `autoplot.zoo` method in zoo (zoo is automatically pulled in by xts) will create plots using ggplot2 for xts objects too.  It supports ggplot2's +... if you need additional geoms.  See `?autoplot.zoo`

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
x_xts <- xts(1:4, as.Date("2000-01-01") + 1:4) # test data

autoplot(x_xts, geom = "point")
```

zoo also has `fortify.zoo` which will convert a zoo or xts object to a data.frame:

```
fortify(x_xts)
```

giving:

```
       Index x_xts
1 2000-01-02     1
2 2000-01-03     2
3 2000-01-04     3
4 2000-01-05     4
```

The `fortify` generic is in ggplot2 so if you do not have ggplot2 loaded then use `fortify.zoo(x_xts)` directly.

See `?fortify.zoo` for more information.

Comment: See also `autoplot` in ggplot2.

Answer (score 10):

change lower case 'index' to upper case 'Index'

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Index, y = value)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use an `xts` object?

You can plot date/times without the use of `xts`. Here is an example using what you provided above. You could format it how you want beyond that.

```
dates <- c("2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
value <- as.numeric(c(3, 4, 5, 6, 5))
new_df <- data.frame(dates, value)
new_df$dates <- as.Date(dates)

require(scales)
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = dates, y = value)) + geom_point() + 
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"), breaks = date_breaks("1 month")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
ggsave("time_plot.png", height = 4, width = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I've found that passing on the data explicitly will work:

```r
my_xts %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Index, y = .)) +
  geom_line()
```

I hope that works for you!