# Is there a way to plot 2 or more series with ggplot2 from an xts object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

Is basically the problem described here [Plotting an xts object using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345388/plotting-an-xts-object-using-ggplot2)

But I can not adapt it to plot two series, the code is the following:

```
dates <- c("2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
values1 <- as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,5))
values2 <- as.numeric(c(10,9,8,7,6))
new_df <- data_frame(dates, values1, values2)
new_df$dates <- as.Date(dates)
new_df <- as.xts(new_df[, -1], order.by = new_df$dates)
```

Now I use ggplot:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Index, y = c(values1, values2))) 
+ geom_point()
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5):
> y Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

It is possible to have both series of this object on the same plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the creation of new_df we revise the calculation in the Note at the end giving the same value but with less code:

- new_df is an xts object, not a data.frame, so let us use x as a more descriptive name
- there is no real point in creating a data frame and then converting it to xts -- just create an xts object directly
- we don't need as.numeric.  Both instances of c(...) are already numeric.
- the ggplot2 command takes data frames, not xts objects. For an xts object use autoplot instead.

Note that `x` in the Note is identical  in contents to `new_df` in the question. We have just used a different name.

Now use `autoplot`.  Omit `the geom="point"` argument if you want lines and omit the `facet=NULL` argument if you want separate panels.  See `?autoplot.zoo` for more examples.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

autoplot(x, geom = "point", facet = NULL) + ggtitle("My Plot")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Input used above.

```
library(xts)
dates <- c("2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
values1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
values2 <- c(10,9,8,7,6)
x <- xts(cbind(values1, values2), as.Date(dates))
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: specify each series as a layer:

```
 ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Index)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = values1, color = "values1")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = values2, color = "values2"))
```

[image]

Option 2: convert to a longer shape of tibble, with series name as a column:

```
library(tidyverse)
new_df %>%
  zoo::fortify.zoo() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  pivot_longer(-Index, names_to = "series", values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = values, color = series)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]